# Python - Is there a way I can web scrape information from the XHR tab on Network?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I've done a ton of research online, read through many of the similar questions on Stack Overflow, but can't find anything too useful.

I'm trying to scrape some information off a housing website for a research paper. I can't use requests (I don't think) because they don't have "name" for their username and password fields, and it's a site that requires login, so I am trying to use Selenium. This website uses infinite scrolling to display their information.

I see all of the information I need is in the XHR tab in the developer tools: [image]

[image]
In fact, the preview tab has exactly the information I need:
[image]

The recommendlist pops up as I scroll on the page.

I was just wondering if there was any way to access the information in this tab using Python, so I can parse and analyze the data?

Is there a different approach I'm not thinking of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Open the web console
2. Go to Network and set XHR
3. At the top you will see "Request URL"
4. Copy it and make requests to this URL via requests/selenium

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't think it can work for this site in particular. The request url is a generic one, and each time I scroll and a new XHR pops, it uses the exact same URL ending in "recommendlist". Any workarounds taht you know of?

Comment: Scroll down. Look for the form data that passed to make a post request. If you could provide the link, I'd help you.